# Column-Header and Row-Header context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, command, contextmenu, wpfdatagrid

I am using WPF datagrid. I am providing context menu for row-header and column-header. The code is as mentioned below:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:WpfApplication10"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Insert Column Before" Command="cmd:ContextMenuCustomCommands.InsertColumnBeforeCommand" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Insert Column After" Command="cmd:ContextMenuCustomCommands.InsertColumnAfterCommand"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="Delete"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="cmd:ContextMenuCustomCommands.InsertColumnBeforeCommand" CanExecute="InserColumnBefore_CanExecute" Executed="InserColumnBefore_Executed"/>
        <CommandBinding Command="cmd:ContextMenuCustomCommands.InsertColumnAfterCommand" CanExecute="InsertColumnAfter_CanExecute" Executed="InsertColumnAfter_Executed"/>
    </Grid.CommandBindings>
    <DataGrid x:Name="grdEmployee" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGeneratingColumn="grdEmployee_AutoGeneratingColumn" LoadingRow="grdEmployee_LoadingRow" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader">

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WpfApplication10
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private SqlConnection empCon = null;
        private SqlCommand empCmd = null;
        private DataSet empDS = null;
        private SqlDataAdapter empAdap = null;
        private string query = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.grdEmployee.ItemsSource = this.GetEmployeeData().DefaultView;
        }

        private DataTable GetEmployeeData()
        {
            try
            {
                empCon = new SqlConnection(Application.Current.Properties["connectionStr"].ToString());
                empCmd = new SqlCommand(query, empCon);
                empAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(empCmd);
                empDS = new DataSet();
                empAdap.Fill(empDS);
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlEx)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                if (empCon != null)
                    empCon.Dispose();

                if (empCmd != null)
                    empCmd.Dispose();
            }

            if (empDS != null)
            {
                for (int count = 1; count <= empDS.Tables[0].Columns.Count; count++)
                {
                    empDS.Tables[0].Columns[count - 1].ColumnName = Utility.ConvertNumber(count).ToString();
                }
                return empDS.Tables[0];
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private void grdEmployee_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void grdEmployee_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString();
        }

        private void InserColumnBefore_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void InserColumnBefore_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void InsertColumnAfter_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void InsertColumnAfter_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Utility
    {
        private static string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        public static string ConvertNumber(int number)
        {
            string result;
            number -= 1;
            int rest = number % 26;
            int q = number / 26;
            if (q == 0)
            {
                result = chars[rest].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                result = ConvertNumber(q) + chars[rest];
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static class ContextMenuCustomCommands
    {
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand InsertColumnBeforeCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Insert Column Before", "Insert Column Before", typeof(MainWindow));
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand InsertColumnAfterCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Insert Column After", "Insert Column After", typeof(MainWindow));
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication10
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            string connectionStr = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=(local);";
            Application.Current.Properties["connectionStr"] = connectionStr;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is, The context menu on column header remain disabled until and unless I access the datagrid. I am not able to figure out the reason.

Please help me. Do let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: When you say "until and unless I access the datagrid", do you mean until you click on and focus on the DataGrid, or until the datagrid has data?

Comment: @CodeWarrior: Yes... if i click on column header, the options in context menu are disabled. If I select a row or select a cell, the the context menu for column-header is enabled.

Comment: @CodeWarrior: Thanks.. I got the solution. I called grid.focus() method on loaded event of grid. Now it is working file. :)

Comment: Is your CanExecute on your command bindings returning false when your app first starts? Sometimes the CanExecute code gets hit twice, you may have a condition that returns false on initialization. This may be something inside of the RoutedUICommand.

Comment: @PriyankThakkar Great!  Glad you got it working.  I will put a blurb in an answer to the above effect so others can see the solution a bit easier.

Comment: @CodeWarrior: If I click on any columnheader it is showing the context menu. Any idea how can I get the column index for it?

Comment: I have previously done this using the following article as a starting point.  http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2008/12/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row/    I will add it to my answer below also.

Comment: @CodeWarrior: I also found the same article. He is subscribing the MouseRightButtonDown event, using the tunneling approach intercepting it at column header level. But as you see from my code, I am using a custom command. In that scenario it is not clear to me how to use the logic mentioned in the blog above.

Comment: If you are using a command, you might be able to pass the column to it as a parameter.  I have not tried this, nor am I at my desk right now.  If you are feeling adventurous, you might give it a shot.  With the column (or possibly columnHeader) in the command logic, you may be able to do your work without further muss.

Comment: @CodeWarrior: hmmmm... let me see :) :)

Comment: @CodeWarrior: I found the solution :) :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809508/find-the-selected-column-in-datagrid/8809741#8809741

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above the problem seemed to be stemming from the fact that the DataGrid was not focused when the click was made.

Calling `gid.Focus();` in the loaded event fixed the problem by bringing focus on the GridView.

As for detecting the column clicked, you can likely get that through an event handler similar to getting Cell and Row information detailed [in this article](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2008/12/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row/)